# Android Screen Marign

Tags: android, eclipse

I use this xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="0px"
    android:src="@drawable/up" />


  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"

    android:layout_marginTop="0px"
    android:src="@drawable/back" />
```

I want set imageView1 to top of screen but imageView has a little space top of screen and imageView not match_parent or fill_parent And I want imageView Below than imageView1 but so has a little space than imageView1.

how can solve it?

Comment: post an image of what is happening and a wireframe of what u want

Comment: Two options (I think). Remove all the `android:padding*` values from `RelativeLayout`. Alternatively, on the `ImageView` use a negative value at `android:layout_marginTop`

Comment: @Tigger remove all padding and solve it,but imageView1 not set to the match_parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do that is to ***REMOVE PADDING FROM PARENT LAYOUT TAG***

Try This Code....

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" <!--Removed unnecessary padding -->
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" <!--Moves To Top of The Screen -->
    android:src="@drawable/up" />


  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1" <!--Moves bellow of imageview1 -->
    android:src="@drawable/back" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: whats the problem therE?

Answer (score 0):

```
**Remove padding**     
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    **//android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    //android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    //android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    //android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"**
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="0px"
        android:src="@drawable/up" />


      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"

        android:layout_marginTop="0px"
        android:src="@drawable/back" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this lines from your parent RelativeLayout.

```
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```